# Dialog box that can be used as a user interface

Tags: forms, dialog, macros, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

I am seeking help to make a form in OpenOffice Calc / LibreOffice using Dialog control and macros. I have to make a Dialog Box that can be used as a user interface which will help me to enter a text, select item from a list, etc. [I made it already but not the preferred macros.]

The problem is I don't know how to connect this dialog box to my sheet. (i.e. when the submit button clicks, the entered data should go to the cells as in a table (downwards). When the next data is entered in the box, it must go to the next cell (like a merchant bill is prepared), so on.

Can anyone please help me or provide necessary examples for this problem?

Comment: I don't think there's a mass-grab-from-dialog-mass-enter-into-Calc method. You'll have to get one value from the dialog, enter that one value into Calc (or into a data array), get the next value from the dialog, etc., until you're at the end (you'll need a method to detect end of data) and then if using a data array set the data array to a Calc range. What kind of form controls are you using on your dialog? What language are you writing the macro in? How far have you gotten with the macro: can you write data to Calc cells (any data, not from the dialog)? Can you grab data out of the dialog?

Comment: Show us the code you've got so far, even if it doesn't work at all. It'll help us get a better idea of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sub UpdateLogWorksheet()
 Dim historyWks As object
    Dim inputWks As object

    Dim nextRow As Long
    Dim oCo1 As Long

    Dim myRng As object
    Dim myCopy As String
    Dim myCell As object
    
    'cells to copy from Input sheet - some contain formulas
    myCopy = "F13,F15,F17,F19,F21,F23"

    Set inputWks = ThisComponent.Sheets(2)
    Set historyWks =ThisComponent.Sheets(1)

    With historyWks
        nextRow = ThisComponent.Sheets(1).Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    End With

    With inputWks
        Set myRng = .Range(myCopy)

Comment: If Application.CountA(myRng) <> myRng.Cells.Count Then
            MsgBox "Please fill in all the cells!Check once again that if you hadn't choosen the urgent option"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    With historyWks
        With .Cells(nextRow, "H")
            .Value = Now
            .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
        End With
        .Cells(nextRow, "I").Value = Application.UserName
        oCol = 5
        For Each myCell In myRng.Cells
            historyWks.Cells(nextRow, oCol).Value = myCell.Value
            oCol = oCol + 1

Comment: Next myCell
    End With
    
    'clear input cells that contain constants
    With inputWks
      On Error Resume Next
         With .Range(myCopy).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
              .ClearContents
              Application.GoTo .Cells(1) ', Scroll:=True
         End With
      On Error GoTo 0
    End With

End Sub